# jquery - reload a page where content was loading within a div

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a datatable where when clicked on a row, it opens an editing page within a set div in the page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "../DataQueries/FetchAllCourts.asp",
            } );

            $('#example tbody tr').live('click', function () {
                var sTitle;
                var nTds = $('td', this);
                var sJobID = $(nTds[0]).text();
                $("#example tbody tr").removeClass('row_selected');        
                 $(this).addClass('row_selected');
                $('#showcourtinfo').load("popcourttable.asp?courtid=" + sJobID);
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

And the div is as such.

```
<div id="showcourtinfo"></div>
```

Now all good, the page does load and I am able to make the necessary changes to the data and save it but I want that the whole page reload or even better, the datatable to reload to show the changes.

I know that you can edit the datatable directly but I would rather use a separate form to do it as there were a lot of fields.

Here is the script

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#savebutton').click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'save/savecourt.asp',
                data: {
                    courtid: $('#courtid').val(),
                    newcourt: $('#courtname').val()
                },
                success: function(result){
                    $('#message').fadeIn("slow");
                    $('#message').fadeOut("slow");
                    window.opener.location.reload();
                }
            });



        });

});
```

I guess I am getting the window.location bit wrong but not sure how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: After saving the changes to database, call a ASP page containing the data table with ajax and display it in the div that contains the data table.

Comment: `window.opener.location.reload()` does not refresh your page?

Comment: tried simple `document.location.reload()`? If I'm guessing right, there is no opener for your current window.

Comment: window.opener.location.reload() did not but location.reload() did. However, I want the user to still see the 'Saved Successfully' message which cannot happen if I reload straight away

Comment: `setTimeout(document.location.reload, 1000);` adjust the time to your liking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your success function to something like below

```
        success: function(result){
            $('#message').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#message').fadeOut("slow").queue(function(){
                document.location.reload();
            });
        }
```